# Test if given ip is a public one?

Tags: java, ip

I'd like to check if the user submitted adress ip is a valid public ip (non loopback, non local, non reserved).

For that purpose, I came up with that method, but I was wondering if this was enough or if I was missing some tests.

Thank you for your help :)

```
private boolean isValidPublicIp(String ip) {
    try
    {
        Inet4Address address = (Inet4Address) InetAddress.getByAddress(ip.getBytes());
        if (!address.isSiteLocalAddress() && !address.isAnyLocalAddress() && !address.isLinkLocalAddress() && !address.isLoopbackAddress() && !address.isMulticastAddress()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException exception) {}

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much of a java answer, but to provide an approach on the IP validation check:
What about using WHOIS?

This would overcome making lists of unused / private addresses and can be checked against real world.

Since WHOIS provides a lot of info, I suggest you only check on specific items, like:

whois 192.168.0.1 | grep NetName:
NetName:        PRIVATE-ADDRESS-CBLK-RFC1918-IANA-RESERVED

whois 80.85.32.1 | grep NetName:
NetName:        80-RIPE

whois 1.1.0.1 | grep NetName:
NetName:        APNIC-1

Since all reserved addresses will have RESERVED at their net names this is an easy way out.
Exception are test nets, like:

whois 192.0.2.1 | grep NetName:
NetName:        TEST-NET-1

and multicast net's like:

whois 224.0.0.1 | grep NetName:
NetName:        MCAST-NET

so the reply check is limited to three options, by match show that the address is not public.